# Herança CSS em Divs

Tags: html, css, div, herança

Estou tendo problemas na edição de algumas divs com herança. Bem vamos ao exemplo:

Este é o código atual:

```
<div id="conteudo">
  <div class="titulo">xxx</div>
  <div class="texto">xxx</div>
  <div class="antesDepois">xxx</div>
  <div class="autor">xxx</div>
  <div class="tags">xxx</div>
  <div class="comentários">xx</div>
</div>
```

Certo, tendo isso em vista, o css dessas divs ja está feito. Só que a div Conteudo está colocando tudo dentro de uma única caixa. Eu queria saber se é possivel eu "dividir" essa caixa ao meio.

Por exemplo, antes da **div class="antesDepois"** eu gostaria de colocar uma divisão. Depois colocar uma divisao novamente na **div class"autor"** e assim por diante.

Aí vocês me falam, mas cara.. É só vc fechar a div conteúdo que e abrir uma nova div antes da **antesDepois**.. Só que não, não posso, por que as divs estão herdando várias coisas da div conteudo.. E são muitas..

Sei que deveria ter feito isso antes, mas estou editando um código que ja foi produzido..

Então fica ai a GRANDE DÚVIDA.. Eu consigo fazer algo a respeito?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com "dividir ao meio"? já tentaste com `nth-child`?

Comment: E não dá pra fechar e abrir outra `div` com a classe `conteudo`. Assim, os outros elementos vão continuar herdando seja lá o que for.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Nossa, é verdade.. Isso irá resolver por hora os meus problemas..

Comment: Submeti como resposta então... já que isso é aceitável. Caso você encontre algum problema que o impeça de usar essa solução, basta deixar um comentário que eu altero a resposta.

Comment: @maxxzag podes responder á minha pergunta em cima?

Comment: @Sergio Claro, digamos que a div "conteudo" tem um css com background-color: #00; logo, todas as outras divs também estão com este background. 

Eu queria que houvesse um divisor entre as divs "texto" e "antesDepois". Porém eu não ia conseguir fazer isso somente mudando o background pois tinha padding envolvido, margin e outras coisas.. E eu gostaria que estas coisas nao estivessem inclusas nas divs.

A resposta do Miguel ajuda por que eu crio outra div com a mesma classe e estas continuam com a herança que elas tinham.

Comment: utilize uma div pai como container para sua separação, ai você pode deixar o comportamento a partir do item acima, ou seja seu container.

Comment: Mas não tinhas dito que não podias mudar o HTML? ou percebí mal aqui: "Só que não, não posso, por que as divs estão herdando várias coisas da div conteudo.. " ?

Answer (score 2):

Se der pra fechar e abrir outra `div` com a classe `conteudo` os outros elementos vão continuar herdando seja lá o que for.

Você terá de alterar o atributo `id` para `class`, se quiser manter o HTML correto. Também terá de alterar os seletores de id que usam `#` para seletores de classe `.`, no CSS e também se usar jQuery.

Assim:

```
<div class="conteudo">
  <div class="titulo">xxx</div>
  <div class="texto">xxx</div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
  <div class="antesDepois">xxx</div>
  <div class="autor">xxx</div>
  <div class="tags">xxx</div>
  <div class="comentários">xx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sergio Minha nossa... eu nem me atentei. Valeu! Alterei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode selecionar os enésimos `div` filhos com CSS3, utilizando `element:nth-child(n)` e assim aplicar uma "divisão" de estilos internamente.

[É possível, ainda, selecionar um intervalo de filhos.](https://gist.github.com/rondevera/167627)

Por exemplo; se você quiser selecionar apenas `.antesDepois` e `.autor`. Dessa forma, queremos os 3º e 4º filhos. Um estilo ficaria assim:

```
#conteudo div:nth-child(n + 3):not(:nth-child(n + 5)) {
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: red;
}
```

No meu exemplo, eu utilizei também o seletor `:not` para ajudar na legibilidade.

[Se quiser, leia mais sobre os seletores no W3Schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)